# JQuery Datepicker is not showing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker

Datepicker is not showing when I click on the textbox.

My view code is as follow .

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>Plane_Schedule</title>
</head>

 <section class="registersection">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="signupForm">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSchedule", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                            <div class="Form1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="Form1">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="editor-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    FROM
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plane_LocFrom)
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plane_LocFrom)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="editor-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    TO
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Plane_LocTo)
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Plane_LocTo)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="Form2">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="editor-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    Departure Time
                                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Dep, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time_Dep)
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="editor-field">
                                                <label>
                                                    Arrival Time
                                                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Arrive, new { @class = "datepicker" })
                                                </label>
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time_Arrive)

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <p>
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                            </p>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


 @section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    }

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateformat: "yy/mm/dd",
                changemonth=true,
                changeyear=true,
                minDate: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
                maxDate: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
                showOn="both",
                buttonText:"Select"
            });
        });

    </script>
```

I want to show the datepicker on Time_Arrive and Time_Dep textboxes when user enter it. I have added the JQuery ui script as well. My JQuery function is written above. I want the user to enter the date between 2018 and 2019.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include a reference the jQuery library before the jQuery UI Script.

Change this section:

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
    }
```

In the above code snippet you are referencing jQuery UI twice (one minified version and one regular version). You only need one of these, but in order for the jQuery UI to work, you first need to reference the jQuery library like below.

To this:

```
 @section scripts{
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Please check my question again. I have also referenced jQuery script in head.

Comment: @StackDeveloper In the head, you have referenced jQuery UI, not jQuery and references to JS files should not be placed here. You should only reference CSS files in the header. You are referencing the JS files correctly in the scripts section but are just missing the jQuery reference, I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Dep, new { @class = "datepicker" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Arrive, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

to:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Dep, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time_Arrive, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
```

`Html.EditorFor` is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object additionalViewData);
```

`Html.TextBoxFor` is (slightly different):

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes);
```

Also note, you've referenced `jquery-ui-1.12.1` twice in your View, the minified and non-minified version. Best to check to make sure that jQuery itself is referenced somewhere in your layout and that you haven't mistakenly referenced `jquery-ui`.

Comment: Please check my question again. I have also referenced jQuery script in head.

Comment: @Stack Developer jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js (in your question) is not jquery, it is jquery UI. You need both, with jQuery referenced above jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

Your script section should look like below.
Jquery reference goes before anything that depends on it.

Heres a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/xpvt214o/57167/)

```
 @section scripts{
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

    }
also add the jquery UI css 
@section styles{
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"
      rel="stylesheet">
}
```

Comment: I have changed this but still not showing. Please check my question again. I have also referenced in head.

Comment: You need jquery AND jqueryui but jquery first. They are two different libraries my dude.